# Keras: how to do weighted addition of outputs of encoders with weights given by another classifier?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

**I need to merge multidimensional outputs of 3 (or more) encoders by weighted addition, and the weights are coming from another classifier**. How do I do this?

basically I need to do this (in a vectorized form):

output = dotProduct([output1, output2, output3], w) = w1*output1 + w2*output2 + w3*output3

Dimensions:

output = output1 = output2 = output3 = [None, 16, 16, 512]

w = [None, 3]

None is the unknown dimension allocated for batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic number of encoders, you could do something along the lines of:

```
def f(x):
    w = x[-1]
    outputs = x[:-1]
    outputs_ = K.concatenate([o[:, None, ...] for o in outputs],
                             axis=1)  # Shape=(None, nb_outputs, 16, 16, 512)

    out = K.sum(w[..., None, None, None] * outputs_,
                axis=1)  # Shape=(None, 16, 16, 512)
    return out

outputs = [output1, output2, output3]  # Works with any number of outputs
output = Lambda(f)(outputs + [w])
```

Comment: Just for clarification, this will allow gradients to flow back to the encoders right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, because everything is differentiable.